# AKS cluster provisioning error Azure Machine Learning service Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy a ML model to AKS following this tutorial https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-deploy-azure-kubernetes-service.

When it comes to creating the cluster using the Python SDK:

```
from azureml.core.compute import AksCompute, ComputeTarget

# Use the default configuration (you can also provide parameters to customize this).
# For example, to create a dev/test cluster, use:
# prov_config = AksCompute.provisioning_configuration(cluster_purpose = AksCompute.ClusterPurpose.DEV_TEST)
prov_config = AksCompute.provisioning_configuration()

aks_name = 'myaks'
# Create the cluster
aks_target = ComputeTarget.create(workspace = ws,
                                    name = aks_name,
                                    provisioning_configuration = prov_config)

# Wait for the create process to complete
aks_target.wait_for_completion(show_output = True)
```

I get the following error:

```
ComputeTargetException: ComputeTargetException:
    Message: Compute object provisioning polling reached non-successful terminal state, current provisioning state: Failed
Provisioning operation error:
StatusCode: 400
Message: The request is invalid
    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Compute object provisioning polling reached non-successful terminal state, current provisioning state: Failed\nProvisioning operation error:\nStatusCode: 400\nMessage: The request is invalid"
    }
}
```

Within the Azure portal the compute target shows with provisioning status failed and the following error: Provisioning error : InvalidTemplateDeployment: The template deployment '0086633c-90b8-466d-9124-7e2cd78c5abc' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is 'f0ca368a-dd3c-4fa3-9daf-ee49c82f41e4'. See inner errors for details.

Client Request ID : fe9ff62f-666d-4b23-b6ff-33cd38f669ff   Service Request ID : |64f42c9db113451395735386668ae64c.

I have tried different VM sizes, but all hit upon the same error. I am deploying within the East US region.